When run onnx with CUDAExecutionProvider, it raise "FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error"
2024-04-01 23:16:16.891282913 [E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1480 TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1193 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I use following cmd find the not found so
~ $ locate libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so
/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so

I guess it's because env PATH issue, how to set PATH to let python onnx find libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so
I try to locate the so, the so exist and manually add so dir to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the err still exist
~/Dropbox/mix/real-esrgan/submodule/Real-ESRGAN $ locate libcublasLt.so
/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublasLt.so.11
/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublasLt.so.12
^[[A~/Dropbox/mix/real-esrgan/submodule/Real-ESRGAlocate libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so
/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so
~/Dropbox/mix/real-esrgan/submodule/Real-ESRGAN $ PYTHON_PATH=. LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib" python onnx/run_onnx.py
2024-04-01 23:50:25.975940926 [E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1480 TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1193 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

2024-04-01 23:50:25.975963148 [W:onnxruntime:Default, onnxruntime_pybind_state.cc:747 CreateExecutionProviderInstance] Failed to create CUDAExecutionProvider. Please reference https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements to ensure all dependencies are met.
out /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/real-esrgan/submodule/Real-ESRGAN/onnx/out.jpg

following is my full onnx code:
import os.path

import onnxruntime
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the ONNX model
d = os.path.abspath(f"{__file__}/..")
onnx_model_path = f'{d}/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx'
ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path, providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider", 'AzureExecutionProvider',
                                                                       'CPUExecutionProvider'])  # in my old deivce with 18.04, cannot install libonnxruntime_providers_cuda, so cannot use cuda
# ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path, providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider"])

# Load and preprocess input image
input_image_path = f"{d}/t.jpg"
input_image = cv2.imread(input_image_path)
input_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert BGR to RGB
input_image = input_image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1]
input_image = np.transpose(input_image, (2, 0, 1))  # Change the shape from HWC to CHW
input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension

# Perform inference
ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: input_image}
ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)

# Post-process the output
output_image = ort_outs[0][0]  # Assuming only one output
output_image = np.transpose(output_image, (1, 2, 0))  # Change the shape from CHW to HWC
output_image = (output_image * 255).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert back to uint8 and clip values

# Display or save the output image
out = f"{d}/out.jpg"  # Adjust output path as needed
cv2.imwrite(out, cv2.cvtColor(output_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
print(f"out {out}")


I think the error is telling you that libcublasLt.so.11 is not found, not the one you locate with the command. Try to search this lib and see whether it’s in your path.

I use locate get all so paths and put so's dirs in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it fix. it's complex way, if there is more simple way, please tell me
PYTHON_PATH=. LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/curand/lib:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cufft/lib:/home/roroco/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cuda_runtime/lib" python onnx/run_onnx.py

